# Running a Python script in Conda virtual environment as service

Tags: python, services, start-stop-daemon, virtualenv, datascience-anaconda

I recently wrote a Python program that is designed to communicate via SMPP SMS server.

The issue I'm facing is that I don't know how to run a Python script as a service on my Cent OS server using Conda virtual environment. I'm using a lot of dependencies and choosing virtual environment over Conda is not an option.

Is there any way I could run this script as a service? Also is there a way to write console methods to start this script using the following?

```
service fooService start
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry this comes late, but the way to run a python script within a particular environment is to write a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source activate my_env && python my_script.py
```

and have that wrapper script as your service instead of the python script itself.

Answer (score 5):

There is also another way. You can directly use the python executable from environment in `ExecStart` like this:

```
ExecStart=/path/to/conda/envs/my_env_name/bin/python /path/to/executable
```

For my CentOS server where I'm using miniconda the path is:

```
ExecStart=/root/miniconda3/envs/test_env/bin/python3 /root/test.py
```

Comment: Not sure how to apply this answer. Instead, I am able to run under conda by placing the python executable path directly in the script as the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

For git-bash, try the following. The first line inits conda.

```
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
source activate myenv
python myscript.py
```